# Iterating over checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with check-boxes, a dropdown, and other accompanying data.

I'd like to iterate over the rows that have been checked, and pull it's data, add that data into a dictionary, then into a master array.

It seems to be finding the correct rows with check boxes, but my for loop is not pulling each row properly. Here is my js code:

```
$("#thechecked").click(function(){
   var send_list = []
   $('#mytable').find(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
      var dict = {};
      var value = $("#presetChoosen").val();
      var filename = $("#filename").text();
      dict['filename'] = filename
      dict['value'] = value
      send_list.push(dict)

   });
   console.log(send_list)

});
```

[FULL EXAMPLE IN JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbfJk/115/)

What  am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the same ids everywhere like you did on the select element. Id's elements are meant to be unique.

I've used some jQuery methods(*`parent(), find(), next()`*) to target the specific values:

```
var value = $(this).parent().parent().find("select option:checked").val();
var filename = $(this).parent().next("td").text();
```

Below is a working snippet of what you're trying to achieve:

```js
$("#thechecked").click(function() {
  var send_list = []
  $('#mytable').find(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    var dict = {};
    var value = $(this).parent().parent().find("select option:checked").val();
    var filename = $(this).parent().next("td").text();
    dict['filename'] = filename
    dict['value'] = value
    send_list.push(dict)

  });
  console.log(send_list)

});
```

```css
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr id="mq">
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>What</td>
      <td>Meta</td>
      <td>Preset</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td id="filename_1">Underthesea</td>
      <td>1920x1080</td>
      <td> <select id="presetChoosen_1">        
                <option value="Watch">Watch</option>
                <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td id="filename_2">Overthehill</td>
      <td>1280x720</td>
      <td> <select id="presetChoosen_2" value="asd">        
                <option value="Watch">Watch</option>
                <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td id="filename">Mocking</td>
      <td>1280x720</td>
      <td> <select id="presetChoosen" value="asd">        
                <option value="Watch">Watch</option>
                <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="thechecked">Get Checked</button>
```

Comment: Ah beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcLeonard, awesome. You're welcome. I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-using id attributes. IDs are supposed to be unique - and I believe it's actually a WC3 validation error to re-use the same ID in HTML.

You're also not scoping your selector to your checkbox at all.

Change your id="" to name="" and then try the following code concept:

```
$('#mytable').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        filename = tr.find('[name="filename"]').val();

    // [...]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the checkbox (inside the loop), then you need to get the row for that checkbox, eg:

```
$("#thechecked").click(function(){
   var send_list = []
   $('#mytable :checkbox:checked').each(function () {
      var row = $(this).closest("tr");

      var value = row.find("#presetChoosen").val();
      var filename = row.find("#filename").text();

      var dict = {};
      dict['filename'] = filename
      dict['value'] = value
      send_list.push(dict)
   });
   console.log(send_list)
});
```

bit hard to be 100% without your HTML (in the question) and it looks like you have elements with the same `id`, eg `id='presetChoosen'` on every row, which is advised against.

Answer (score 0):

Like the accepted answer said, [ids should be unique](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/id-html-attribute/). What I would do is change `filename` and `presetChoosen` to classes instead, since they are a type of thing (`class`), not a particular thing (`id`). That way you could traverse the DOM in a more readable and easier to understand way:

```js
$("#thechecked").click(function(){
   var send_list = [];
   $('#mytable').find(':checkbox:checked').each(function (index, checkbox) {

      // Find the row this checkbox is in
      var row = $(checkbox).closest('tr'),
        value = row.find('.presetChoosen').val(),
        filename = row.find('.filename').text();

      send_list.push({
        filename: filename,
        value: value
      });

   });
   console.log(send_list);

});
```

```css
tr,td{border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
    <tr id="mq">
        <td></td>
        <td>What</td>
        <td>Meta</td>
        <td>Preset</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="filename" >Underthesea</td>
        <td>1920x1080</td>
        <td> <select class="presetChoosen">
                <option value="Watch">Watch</option>
                <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="filename" >Overthehill</td>
        <td>1280x720</td>
        <td> <select class="presetChoosen">
                <option value="Watch">Watch</option>
                <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3">
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="filename" >Mocking</td>
        <td>1280x720</td>
        <td> <select class="presetChoosen">
                <option value="Watch">Watch</option>
                <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
                <option value="None">None</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="thechecked">Get Checked</button>
```